# How to redirect "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found" to an error information page in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

In tomcat, an invalid link can throw a `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found` as follows.

[image]

How to configure `tomcat` to redirect it to an error information page, such as `The request is invalid!` if such a case happens?

Comment: @logger it's not really true. That works only in a given web application. If a link doesn't fall into any given or known application, there is no way to try .. catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add the following to file `ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/yourLocationToredirect</location>
</error-page>
```

Also write a message in any html or jsp and add this page as redirect location

The following link discussed the same question https://serverfault.com/questions/254102/custom-error-pages-on-apache-tomcat